# Google chrome, mouse and keyboard weird behavior

Tags: 20.04, keyboard, mouse, google-chrome

I have deleted and reinstalled google chrome twice but the problem is not going away.Simply put on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS my mouse is moving but not clicking , on google chrome random windows open every time I move the mouse over an advertisement. I installed the software clamscan and I did a full disk scan and I got no viruses or malware detected over the root / directory and recursively into  the home directories[image: clamscan final output] When I use my keyboard with google chrome suddenly random links pop up or the HTML code shows up. Is this a hardware issue i.e. do I need to replace my keyboard and mouse or is there a software issue ? With Mozilla firefox the behavior is far better but even here occasionally few links pop up without me doing anything.

I have Ubuntu 20.04 LTS installed on a Dell Optiflex 7050 with no dual boot(no Windows partition). Last time I ran a system diagnostics I did not detect anything unusual with my machine.

Comment: Sounds like the mouse is bad try another one.

Comment: @David Thanks for your answer. And how do you explain the difference in behavior between Chrome and Firefox ?

Comment: You say they both do it just not as often in Firefox so nothing to explain.

Comment: @David would you recommend I change the keyboard as well ?

Comment: Simply put, try in a live session. If the problem persists then it's obviously hardware. If not then troubleshoot the software part, namely what extension/addons you have installed in Chrome (and no, reinstalling without deleting its hidden settings folder does nothing).

Comment: @ChanganAuto Thanks for your response.  Where is the hidden settings folder ?

Comment: @David you can write you answer.  I will accept it. Your solution worked for me. A simple change of mouse has fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the mouse is bad. A new mouse may fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Go to a mouse test site and make sure all the buttons of your mouse are working correctly.